# UIActionSheet in iOS7 dismissing when user taps ANYWHERE on the screen on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiactionsheet, ios7

I've noticed that in `iOS 7 a **UIActionSheet** automatically dismisses` when a `user taps anywhere on the screen on an **iPhone**`. This was NOT the case in iOS 6 and is leading to unintended effects. **`Is this a UI change? Bug? Is there a way to disable this?`**

> [From iOS 7 docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIKitUICatalog.pdf)
>  "As described in iOS human interface
>   guidelines, you should include a Cancel button with action sheets
>   displayed on iPhone and with those displayed on iPad over an open
>   popover. Otherwise on iPad, action sheets are displayed within a
>   popover, and the user can cancel the action sheet by tapping outside
>   the popover, in which case you do not need to include a Cancel
>   button."

This seems to suggest that the behavior of dismissing when tapping anywhere outside the action sheet should only pertain to iPads. But this is now happening on an iPhone running iOS 7 when it doesn't on an iPhone running iOS 6

Comment: I've found that the dismissing when user taps anywhere on the screen only occurs if there is a cancel button, which can allow you to get around this issue by not having a cancel button.

Comment: I am finding UIActionSheet is not getting dismissed after a single button tap - you need to tap on the button twice ! This happens if I use -[UIActionSheet showInView:]. Any workarounds ?

Comment: I am finding UIActionSheet is not getting dismissed after a single button tap - you need to tap on the button twice ! This happens if I use -[UIActionSheet showInView:]. Any workarounds ? I have a UICollectionView datasource in which I do invoke [actionSheet showInView:self.controller.view]. It takes 2 clicks to dismiss.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm not having that problem. Does the action sheet have a cancel button. If so, does it dismiss if you tap OUTSIDE of the action sheet?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you do not want this behavior?

Comment: @Scott the reason I don't want this behavior is because I absolutely want the user to make a decision on the action sheet. There is a good possibility that the user is already tapping the screen a lot when the action sheet comes up, so the user might accidentally be tapping outside of the action sheet when it comes up and thus dismiss it before the user can read it and make a choice.

Comment: @nvrtdfrst: Then not having a cancel button seems the way to go. If you want the user to make a choice, and canceling isn't an option, then you shouldn't provide a cancel button.

Comment: Not trying to hijack this thread but just to note I am getting same thing as Deepak Sharma, two taps needed on cancel button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question **`Is this a UI change? Bug?`**

It is seems like an `UI change not a bug` how can I say that ?
 Have a look at the image i took from iOS7 simulator

It is a image of Maps application of iPhone.
[image]

When you click on button ( display in red rectangle ) one action sheet will display `which have Cancel button` like below 
[image]

And if you click any where else it will close, same behaviour also found in other Apple applications also like safari.

Regarding your question `Is there a way to disable this?`
Sorry but i don't have answer for that.

Comment: So "feature, not a bug." Apple is the new Microsoft.

Comment: If you don't use a cancel button, the Action Sheet will not dismiss if tapped outside.

Answer (score 3):

A word before I post my solution. It is very easy to fear a minor change in behavior and to want to disable it right away. But consider first consistency. This is how action sheets behave across the operating system. If you disable this behavior, you will break consistency and this will result in a subpar experience for your users.

That said, here is my solution.

---

`UIActionSheet` on iPhone opens its view in a separate `UIWindow` instance which becomes key when it is shown. You can access this window using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`. If you inspect the view hierarchy of this window, you will notice several private classes such as dimming view. You can recursively traverse this view hierarchy and set `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` to every view there that is not a subclass of `UIButton`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

As @nvrtdfrst implies in his comments, setting `cancelButton: nil` will get rid of the default dismissal behavior. But you can still have a cancel button by setting the text for one of the custom buttons to `@"Cancel"`--to be treated by the delegate method, something like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
     if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
         // your cancellation code here
     }
}
```

A bit hacky, but that's a simple solution.

H/T: [null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256815/1431728).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstOption" sender:self];
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondOption" sender:self];
    } else if (buttonIndex != 0 || buttonIndex != 1) {
        [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex];
    }

}
```